# Do these prepositions give a different sense to the sentences? (at vs for)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositions

*"A stately hotel in Grimsby has been reluctantly put up for sale by its owner **for** nearly £3 million."*

*"A stately hotel in Grimsby has been reluctantly put up for sale by its owner **at** nearly £3 million."*

Does the meaning of the sentence vary from "for" to "at" even if it's very subtle?

Answer (score 1):

Both prepositions are equally and completely correct, and either one is a natural choice. To me, there is a subtle difference here, but I doubt I would have consciously noticed it without this question.

*For* suggests a price listing or statement; it's simply informational. Emphasis is on the exchange of the hotel for money.

*At* puts the emphasis on the price itself, and suggests that the number is unusual, subject to change or negotiation, or (most likely given *reluctantly*) not the seller's desired target amount.

There are also, I suppose, trivial stylistic differences. Using *at* avoids *for ... for* in quick succession. It also sounds slightly more British to me, though my native English is US, where *for* would be more common.

Comment: I  feel the same for the sentence containing "at", It's like £3 million is offered as a begining  price and it might be risen by the seller during the process.